# how to remove www from domain name and enforce https?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wan to achieve two things

1. remove www from domain name
2. enforce https

i.e.

```
http:// www.example.org  should be redirect to https://example.org
https:// www.example.org  should be redirect to https://example.org
```

**UPDATE:**

I am currently using following .htaccess rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This rule does remove the www from url if present, I redirects the user to https. This happens only when I have www in url. If I access my site with http://exampl.org it doesn't redirect it to https. How can I achieve both?

1) remove www from url

2) enforece https

Here is my htaccess file, I have been trying the mentioned answers but doesn't seems to be working

```
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Better website experience for IE users
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
    #  github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
    # Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
      # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
      <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # CORS-enabled images (@crossorigin)
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
    # developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
    # blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
    # hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/
    # wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/crossoriginAttribute

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
        <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
          SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>


    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Webfont access
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
    # Alternatively you could only whitelist your
    # subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>


    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Proper MIME type for all files
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # JavaScript
    #   Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways)
    #   tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    AddType application/javascript         js jsonp
    AddType application/json               json

    # Audio
    AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg
    AddType audio/mp4                      m4a f4a f4b

    # Video
    AddType video/ogg                      ogv
    AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v f4v f4p
    AddType video/webm                     webm
    AddType video/x-flv                    flv

    # SVG
    #   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
    #   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
    AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

    # Webfonts
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                  otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff        woff

    # Assorted types
    AddType image/x-icon                        ico
    AddType image/webp                          webp
    AddType text/cache-manifest                 appcache manifest
    AddType text/x-component                    htc
    AddType application/xml                     rss atom xml rdf
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension      crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension       oex
    AddType application/x-xpinstall             xpi
    AddType application/octet-stream            safariextz
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
    AddType text/x-vcard                        vcf
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash       swf
    AddType text/vtt                            vtt

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Gzip compression
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

      # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
      <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
          SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
          RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
      </IfModule>

      # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
      <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
      </IfModule>

    </IfModule>


    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Expires headers (for better cache control)
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # These are pretty far-future expires headers.
    # They assume you control versioning with filename-based cache busting
    # Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache
    #   www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

    # If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS and JS to something like
    # "access plus 1 week".

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive on

    # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
      ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
      ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Your document html
      ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Data
      ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Feed
      ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
      ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

    # Media: images, video, audio
      ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

    # HTC files  (css3pie)
      ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

    # Webfonts
      ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

    # CSS and JavaScript
      ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"

    </IfModule>

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # ETag removal
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # FileETag None is not enough for every server.
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
    </IfModule>

    # Since we're sending far-future expires, we don't need ETags for
    # static content.
    #   developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
    FileETag None

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Start rewrite engine
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and
    # features. FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.

    # Some cloud hosting services require RewriteBase to be set: goo.gl/HOcPN
    # If using the h5bp in a subdirectory, use `RewriteBase /foo` instead where
    # 'foo' is your directory.

    # If your web host doesn't allow the FollowSymlinks option, you may need to
    # comment it out and use `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`, but be aware of the
    # performance impact: goo.gl/Mluzd

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymlinks
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>


    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # The same content should never be available under two different URLs -
    # especially not with and without "www." at the beginning, since this can cause
    # SEO problems (duplicate content). That's why you should choose one of the
    # alternatives and redirect the other one.

    # By default option 1 (no "www.") is activated.
    # no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

    # If you'd prefer to use option 2, just comment out all option 1 lines
    # and uncomment option 2.

    # IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Option 1:
    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com".

    #<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
     # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
     # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    #</IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

        #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} off [OR]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
        #RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE, L, R]

        #RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME} %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
      RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]


        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^www\.)
        #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
        #RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>

    #<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #  RewriteEngine On
    #  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    #  RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    #  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    #  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
    #</IfModule>

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Prevent 404 errors for non-existing redirected folders
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # without -MultiViews, Apache will give a 404 for a rewrite if a folder of the
    # same name does not exist.
    # webmasterworld.com/apache/3808792.htm

    Options -MultiViews


    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Custom 404 page
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # You can add custom pages to handle 500 or 403 pretty easily, if you like.
    # If you are hosting your site in subdirectory, adjust this accordingly
    #    e.g. ErrorDocument 404 /subdir/404.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # UTF-8 encoding
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    # Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml


    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # A little more security
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # To avoid displaying the exact version number of Apache being used, add the
    # following to httpd.conf (it will not work in .htaccess):
    # ServerTokens Prod

    # "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
    # default document Usually you should leave this activated, because you
    # shouldn't allow everybody to surf through every folder on your server (which
    # includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
    <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
      Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    # Block access to "hidden" directories or files whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such as
    # Subversion or Git.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
      RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
    </IfModule>

    # Block access to backup and source files. These files may be left by some
    # text/html editors and pose a great security danger, when anyone can access
    # them.
    <FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
      Satisfy All
    </FilesMatch>

    # Increase cookie security
    <IfModule php5_module>
      php_value session.cookie_httponly true
    </IfModule>



    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
        #    RewriteBase /
        #</IfModule>

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]


    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had this working with following htaccess rules, as mentioned in my comment the rules posted in other answers were not working because of the elastic load balancer in place in my environment. All the HTTPS requests going through the ELB will have the value of X-FORWARDED-PROTO equal to “HTTPS“.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.+) [OR,NC]   
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http s://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: yes I have tried this it too gives me the same error as mentioned above, I am thinking may be some other rule in my htaccess file causing the error I am checking it.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

To remove `www` and to enforce `https` you can use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Option 2, on apache 2.4 you can also use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^http#(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: @Anubhava thanks . I have fixed the conditions. is that ok now?

Comment: Yes it is fine now, I will delete my answer since both answers have become same now

Comment: with above rules I am getting error message as: 
The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. The rule is working fine on my server.

Comment: I am using private  window in firefox and cognito mode in chrome, also tried with clearing cache still getting the error

Comment: sorry for late reply 
@anubhava added current htaccess file content

Comment: You have multiple rules adding `www` and `https`. Comment out all of them, keep this one and fully clear browser cache.

Comment: I think I have commented out the other rules for adding www and https only active rule is under <ifmodule> next to label "Option 1:" can you please help me out to find out the extra rules

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

with this rule in place I don't get any error, it removes www from url but doesn't redirct to https,  however if I try comment this rule and add the rule mentioned in answer I get error.

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Comment: Apache API Version: 20120211

Comment: @starkeen with option 2 I am not getting any error, it works :)  however https is not enforced. It does removes the www from url though

Comment: @Rahul both rules are working for me. the 2nd rule i just posted works fine if i go to **http://domain** or **http://www.domain** and it redirects me to **https://domain** howerver it doesnt remove www on https, https://www. doesnt get redirected to https://domain.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use this :




    `<if "%{REQUEST_SCHEME} ='http'">
    Redirect / https://example.com/
    </if>`

Comment: the problem was at my load balancer end, LB was forwarding all request to port 80 instead of 443, now the answer works fine for me,  Thanks !!